# OCR symbol vs non-symbol detection/recognition

Tags: ocr, symbols, pattern-recognition

in an OCR application you'd usually find connected components of the image and run you OCR engine on those components to recognise them.

My question is what should one do if your connected components has symbols/shapes that donot exist in your training set.

For example, if we're running digit recognition and the image has a straight-line or a char, say "X" or anything else which is not a digit.

How can you tell that it's not a digit?

Comment: Your OCR library would most likely provide more information than its guess, such as how accurate the approximation is believed to be. Use this information.

Comment: If you are building your own recognition engine, or at least training one, than you might consider introducing a number of "clutter" examples, to help the system make exactly this sort of determination.

Answer (score 1):

Normally OCR engines provides the confidence score for each symbol recognized. If you set an acceptance threshold on this confidence score you can distinguish between digits and non-digit information.
Good luck